# Files Missing From BigQuery Historic Events Table

Tags: google-bigquery

We use the BigQuery Sandbox integration in Firebase to pull all of our app reporting. For one of our projects, it looks like a number of historic event tables are missing. I've checked the logs in GCP and it doesn't appear that anyone has deleted them.

Could someone offer assistance on what could cause this to happen and how to retrieve the missing files?

Thanks!

Comment: Review: Consider putting ths Q on https://serverfault.com , feels more like a sys-admin question than a programmes question.

Comment: Thank you. I've posted on serverfault as well.